# CSS - Contact form animation

Tags: html, css

```css
.nb-hm-contact-left {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.nb-hm-contact-grid {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

input,
textarea {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f8f8f8;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

&:focus+.nb-label-text,
&:valid+.nb-label-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #282828;
    bottom: 40px;
}

.nb-label-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: text;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

textarea {
    height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
        <input type="text" required />
        <div class="nb-label-text">Name*</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
        <input type="email" required />
        <div class="nb-label-text">Email address*</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
        <input type="text" required />
        <div class="nb-label-text">Company Name*</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <div class="nb-label-text">What’s your project about?*</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to create a contact form using css only. When we click on each field the place holder have to move up. I have created but it's not perfect. The email field and textarea field are not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations don't use fixed values (like bottom: 40px) because height of your elements are different, You can use whole height and 
remove tiny padding from it, Example:

```
input:focus+.nb-label-text,
textarea:focus+.nb-label-text,
input:valid+.nb-label-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #282828;
    bottom: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all change the div to label for .nb-label-text class. Second, change the plus sign (+) to this one ~ after :focus and :valid. And I recommend adding class to input and textarea (I added bodytext) and for textarea add required="" too. All the changes I mentioned are in this new code snippet. :)

This is my version of this contact form [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/54709evn/1/) :)

```css
.nb-hm-contact-left {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.nb-hm-contact-grid {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.bodytext {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f8f8f8;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.bodytext:focus ~ .nb-label-text,
.bodytext:valid ~ .nb-label-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #282828;
    bottom: 40px;
}
label.nb-label-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: text;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
<input type="text" class="bodytext" required="">
<label class="nb-label-text">Name*</label>
</div>
<div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
<input type="email" class="bodytext" required="">
<label class="nb-label-text">Email address*</label>
</div>

<div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
<input type="text" class="bodytext" required="">
<label class="nb-label-text">Company Name*</label>
</div>

<div class="nb-hm-contact-grid row-fluid">
<textarea class="bodytext" required=""></textarea>
<label class="nb-label-text">What’s your project about?*</label>
</div>        
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Kristers Dzintars, thanks for the response. We have a problem in your code. When click on email field the text will move up, but after when you click next field after giving email address the place holder moving down. can we avoid that?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention that. You need to change the type from email to text. You can check the link I added to the answer.

Comment: also, the animation is not working when we click on the place holder. Now we should click on other part of the the same field to make it happen.

Comment: Is it a good practice to give type=text for instead of email? Please reply thanks :)

Comment: Thats because you click on that label object not on input, I have made similar contact form but haven't found any solutions for that.

Comment: Ok Kristers Dzintars, thank you so much for your reply :)

Comment: It won't change anything I tried it. When you click on that input and on that person icon (thats autofill) to the right side of input (that icon is on safari I don't know how is it on chrome) it shows the emails you have registered and when on name it shows your name. So everything works fine no need to worry :)

Comment: Maybe you can give me your social media or email, so I can write you if i find solution for that problem when click on placeholder it doesn't click on input :)

Comment: Hey, I found solution for that problem!